# How to upload files,create folder into repo using api

Tags: php, api, github, github-api

Hi i m using [GitHub v3](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/) and i want to add new binery file in repo .by using [KnpLabs php-github-api](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api) i m exectly doing what says in

1. get the current commit object
2. retrieve the tree it points to
3. retrieve the content of the blob object that tree has for that particular file path
4. change the content somehow and post a new blob object with that new content, getting a blob SHA back
5. post a new tree object with that file path pointer replaced with your new blob SHA getting a tree SHA back

and soo on . but on 5 point i got an exseption

```
server error
```

form this code

```
$comit=$client->api('git')->commits()->show($userName,$reposit,'master');
$basetree=$client->api('git')->trees()->show($userName,'appwiz',$comit['commit']    ['tree']['sha']);

$newBlob=$client->api('git')->blobs()->create($userName,$reposit,array('content'=> "gitapi",'encoding'=>'base64'));

$client->authenticate($userName,$password,Github\Client::AUTH_HTTP_PASSWORD);
$treeData = array(
        'tree'=>
        array(  array('path'=>'/'
                ,'mode'=>'040000'
                ,'type'=>'tree'
                ,'content'=>'folder')
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot

> As part of our ongoing effort to keep GitHub focused on building software, we
>   are deprecating the Downloads Tab. The Downloads API is officially deprecated
>   and will be disabled in 90 days.

[`github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads`](http://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression you needed a valid sha before you could create a tree. Based on the [documentation for creating a tree](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) it seems you need to get the SHA1 of the object. So it seems you might have to have already added the tree to the index. Without that you won't be able to get the SHA of the object as git has recognized it.

Comment: thanks man for your information .i guess you are right .but is there any way to todo all these things.

Comment: "local commit has to be made before you can push it via the API." can u give me any prof or reference

Comment: I updated my answer because I was answering a question that wasn't asked. Also, I was thinking of the Commits API instead of the Blob and Tree APIs.